# how to link custom section to executable with msvc?

Tags: visual-c++

I did put my variable into my_custom_section. The section is present in static library. Yet is not in the executable. How do I configure my cmake so that linker keeps my_custom_section in the executable? I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0.

CMakeLists.txt

```
project(test)

add_library(build_info STATIC build_info.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} build_info)
```

build_info.c

```
#pragma section(".my_custom_section", read, write)
__declspec(allocate(".my_custom_section"))
unsigned char _c_repos_build_build_info[] = { 0x00 };
unsigned int _c_repos_build_build_info_len = 1;
```

list sections in build_info.lib

```
> dumpbin Debug\build_info.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Debug\build_info.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

           4 .data
         104 .debug$S
          58 .debug$T
          57 .drectve
           1 .my_custom_section
```

list sections in executable

```
>dumpbin Debug\test.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Debug\test.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        1000 .data
        1000 .gfids
        2000 .idata
        1000 .pdata
        3000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        9000 .text
```

Comment: Actually reference the variables in your EXE. Barring that, you could use [`/INCLUDE` linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/include-force-symbol-references) to force them into the EXE even though not referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have older cmake in project so I have to use

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/include:build_info")
```

but in never version you could probably use `target_link_options`.